# .NET IHttpHandlers - different session in each AJAX request

Tags: .net, ajax, session, jsonp, ihttphandler

I'm writing a jQuery Mobile app that makes several AJAX requests to a few different `IHttpHandler` classes on my server.  The handlers all return JSON or JSONP, and include the `context.Session.SessionID` in the JSON, for debugging purposes.  I make one request to the first handler, and get back session ID "2jysbehwyxlne0knatltcb2z".  I make another request to a different handler, and get back session ID "qy3v251fxrxesbgqeobqvaza".  This is within a few seconds of each other.  What is going on?  I would expect the session ID to be the same until the session expires after an extended time.

When I open the requests in their own tabs, as opposed to via AJAX in the same tab, I get the same session ID back.  So for my request to authenticate and then my other request to retrieve data, when these requests happen as AJAX requests in a page, the session IDs are different.  When I browse the Network tab in Chrome's console and right-click, Open Link in New Tab each of the requests, they function as expected, having the same session ID.

I am running the jQuery Mobile application on `http://localhost`, and making requests to handlers at `https://localhost`, if this matters.  All of my handlers implement `IRequiresSessionState`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526502/preserve-session-variables-across-httphandlers) looks the same as mine, and its only answer is to implement `IRequiresSessionState`, which I'm doing already.

**Edit:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779455/using-jquery-jsonp-internet-explorer-isnt-saving-the-asp-net-sessionid) might be related, but I'm observing this behavior in Chrome.

**Edit:** I'm using jQuery's `getJSON` function to make the AJAX request.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930650/jquery-getjson-doesnt-send-cookies) about `getJSON` and cookies might be relevant.

Comment: Have you checked that your cookies are being passed properly? Check if the value is set in your asp.net session cookie

Comment: Looks like the cookie only gets set when I make a regular HTTP request to the handler in a browser tab.  I see the session ID in the cookie that was returned in my JSON that way.  When I then try to load my page where the request is made via AJAX, the session ID in the cookie remains the same, and the session ID returned via the AJAX request is different from the one in the cookie.

Comment: Could you share your ajax calling code? And also your current domain. There must be something wrong there.

Comment: Hm, I'm using jQuery's `getJSON` function.  I'll update my question with a related link.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem may have been that I was using jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method for sending the AJAX request.  I ended up adding `<sessionState cookieless="true" />` to my Web.config, so now my handlers stick `S(the_session_id))` into the URL.  When I send my first request to the handler, I store the session ID returned in my JSON in HTML 5 local storage.  All subsequent requests, I pass that session ID in the URL.  This isn't an ideal solution, and I may investigate further to see if I can use cookies for my session again.

Comment: I have not faced a problem with getJSON. Browsers send the cookies with those ajax requests as well.